# jquery reorder li on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, onclick

I have the below jquery which prepends the clicked menu item to the top of the unordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

What I want to have happen instead of moving it to the top of the list I want to place it after the next item I click on in the list.  For example if I click on 2 then 3 the list item with the value of 2 would move after 3 in the list so the html would look like this.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

I have attempted to do this with the below jQuery [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUHLA/), this works the first time I click on 2 then 3 but it doesn't work if you continue to click.  How can this be achieved?

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var test = this;
    console.log($(this).text());
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $(this).after(test);
    });
    //$(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps should you consider using sortable lists? http://forresst.github.io/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, what you might need is to store the first click element and then use it in the second click like below

```
jQuery(function(){
    var item;
    $('li').on('click', function () {
        if (item) {
            $(this).after(item)
            item = undefined;
        } else {
            item = this;
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jx7Aq/)

Comment: one thing I didn't consider in the original question was how to handle sub lists eg <li>2<ul><li>11</li><li>22</li></ul></li> this doesn't seem to work with what you have done becuase when I click on the sub item 22 it still acts as though I have clicked on its parent. eg http://jsfiddle.net/g55CU/ can you think of what I can target here instead?

Comment: @ak85 when you click on the child `li` what should happen?

Comment: Thanks. ideally I would like the sub items to have the same behaviour eg if you click 22 you can move it out of the sub list into the main list. I understand I will need to build something on top of this to add the ability to make an item a sub of an existing item or move it after (which is probably out of the scope of the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.before()` and `.after()` with `.next()` and `.prev()`

```
$('ul li span:nth-of-type(1)').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().before($(this).parent());
});

$('ul li span:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next().after($(this).parent());
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zJ8hd/1/)</kbd>

So, here we go with the explanation, here am selecting the first `span` using `nth-` selectors and than onclick, we move the parent of the `span` i.e `li` before the previous `li` and the second one is the opposite of the same.

Can shorten up the above code by caching up the element like

```
$('ul li span:nth-of-type(1)').on('click', function() {
    moveup =  $(this).parent();
    moveup.prev().before(moveup);
});

$('ul li span:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function() {
    movedown =  $(this).parent();
    movedown.next().after(movedown);
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/zJ8hd/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try this ..its working...

```
 $('li').on('click', function() {
        var test = this;
        $(this).next("li").after(test);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().after($(this));
});
```

This will help you change the order as well